# Puppeteer - Check if xPath element is visible

Tags: node.js, xpath, puppeteer

Hi I'm trying to check if an element on the page is visible or not.

Firstly I would like to say that I'm aware of the solution here:

```
async function isVisible(page, selector) {
  return await page.evaluate((selector) => {
    var e = document.querySelector(selector);
    if (e) {
      var style = window.getComputedStyle(e);

      return style && style.display !== 'none' && style.visibility !== 'hidden' && style.opacity !== '0';
    }
    else {
      return false;
    }
  }, selector);
}
```

However this does not work with xPaths.

Is there a solution to return a `true` or `false` about an elements visibility using xPath?

I'm thinking of something like this

```
async function isVisible(page, xPathSelector){}

//Returns true or false
await isVisible(page, "//button[type='button' and text() = 'Click Me']");
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you be a bit more explicit about this button? Is this a button that is not present on the page then `appears`? or is it always on page? Is there more than one button on page but ONLY one has "click me" ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can suggest 2 variants: with automatical visibility check and manual check.

```js
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';

const browser = await puppeteer.launch(/* { headless: false, defaultViewport: null } */);

try {
  const [page] = await browser.pages();

  await page.goto('https://example.org/');

  console.log(await isVisible1(page, '//p')); // true
  console.log(await isVisible1(page, '//table')); // false

  console.log(await isVisible2(page, '//p')); // true
  console.log(await isVisible2(page, '//table')); // false
} catch(err) { console.error(err); } finally { await browser.close(); }

async function isVisible1(page, xPathSelector){
  try {
    await page.waitForXPath(xPathSelector, { visible: true, timeout: 1000 });
    return true;
  } catch {
    return false;
  }
}

async function isVisible2(page, xPathSelector){
  const [element] = await page.$x(xPathSelector);
  if (element === undefined) return false;

  return await page.evaluate((e) => {
    const style = window.getComputedStyle(e);
    return style && style.display !== 'none' && style.visibility !== 'hidden' && style.opacity !== '0';
  }, element);
}
```

Comment: Ur a genius. Thank u!